# Stop words nltk/python problem

Tags: python, nltk

I have some code that processes a dataset for later use, the code i'm using for the stop words seems to be ok, however I think the problem lies within the rest of my code as it seems to only remove some of the stop words.

```
import re
import nltk

# Quran subset
filename = 'subsetQuran.txt'

# create list of lower case words
word_list = re.split('\s+', file(filename).read().lower())
print 'Words in text:', len(word_list)

word_list2 = [w for w in word_list if not w in nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')]



# create dictionary of word:frequency pairs
freq_dic = {}
# punctuation and numbers to be removed
punctuation = re.compile(r'[-.?!,":;()|0-9]') 
for word in word_list2:
    # remove punctuation marks
    word = punctuation.sub("", word)
    # form dictionary
    try: 
        freq_dic[word] += 1
    except: 
        freq_dic[word] = 1


print '-'*30

print "sorted by highest frequency first:"
# create list of (val, key) tuple pairs
freq_list2 = [(val, key) for key, val in freq_dic.items()]
# sort by val or frequency
freq_list2.sort(reverse=True)
freq_list3 = list(freq_list2)
# display result
for freq, word in freq_list2:
    print word, freq
f = open("wordfreq.txt", "w")
f.write( str(freq_list3) )
f.close()
```

The output is looking like this

```
[(71, 'allah'), (65, 'ye'), (46, 'day'), (21, 'lord'), (20, 'truth'), (20, 'say'), (20, 'and')
```

This is just a small sample, there are others that should have been removed.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

try stripping your words while making your word_list2

```
word_list2 = [w.strip() for w in word_list if w.strip() not in nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')]
```

Comment: `if not w in ...` or `if w not in ...` ?

Comment: Yes. (To clarify: suppose you have "yes ... and, no." somewhere in the text; then `word_list` will contain `yes`, `...`, `and,`, `no.` and `and,` and `no.` will not be stopwords even if `and` and `no` are.) [This is in response to Rafi, not to eumiro. @eumiro, both should work and I doubt there's much difference in either performance or clarity.]

Comment: Stripping doesn't change any output unfortunately :( I doubt it's the stop list that's in the wrong, just can't figure out why it's not working.

Comment: try this    `word_list2 = [w.strip() for w in word_list if w.strip() not in nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')]`

Comment: Nope, still leaves me with 'and' 'the' 'it' etc.

Comment: you should do punctuation.sub on word_list before creating word_list2

Comment: Of course! thank you so much, stupid mistake was bugging me for hours!